# Getting the .php Page Name Dynamically

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab the current pages name dynamically so if for example the Url is:`http://example.com/folder/page395.php?one=two` then what I want is the `page395.php` part.  How do I do this?

Comment: http://php.net/substr

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$the_name=basename(__FILE__);
```

if your not taking about the page your on change `__FILE__` to the url variable

Answer (score 0):

You can grab that part like this, if you are trying to get path that is real file name from url:

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

or:

```
echo basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Comment: those will NOT rerturn the same results, it depends on how they are used.  `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`  will return the path of the file it was included in it include was used.